# $f$ convergent $\implies\lim f'=0$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Consider the following statement:

> Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R})$ and
>   $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0.$

I'm not sure whether my proof is correct:

Assume $h:=\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)\neq0$, without loss of generality $h>0$. So there exists $x_0>0$ so that $\forall x\geq x_0: f'(x)>h/2.$ From the convergence of $f$ follows $$\forall \epsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\geq N: |f(n)-f(n+1)|<\epsilon.$$ From Taylor follows that there is a sequence $x_n\in[n,n+1]$ with $f'(x_n)=f(n+1)-f(n)$. For $\epsilon=h/2$ we get for all $n$ big enough $$h/2>|f(n)-f(n+1)|=|f'(x_n)|>h/2,$$ a contradiction.

EDIT: We have to make the additional assumption, that $f'$ converges. So the statement should be:

> Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R})$ and
>   $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exist, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0.$

Comment: It is possible that $lim f'$ does not converge, so I think you need to discuss that case.

Comment: Your statement is false. Try $f(x) = { \sin x^3 \over 1 + x^2}$ for example.

Comment: Your argument works if you assume $f'$ converges. (Except you are using the mean value theorem and not Taylor's theorem here.)

Comment: If $f'$ converges, then the limit value must be 0, as you proved.

Comment: Thank you. I will add this assumption to the question.

Comment: @Zarrax: I thought about the Cauchy form of the remainder, when I used Taylor's theorem. In this case it coincides with the mean value theorem.

Comment: @mag Ok, then the argument looks fine to me.

Comment: @mag you might also want to clarify that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ should exist as a finite number. Because it's possible that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ could be anything.

Comment: @bjorn93 This is what I actually meant by 'the limit exists'. I learned the definition that the limit has to be a real number and thus finite. What you mean I learned under a name which could be translated into english (sry, I don't know the english word for it) by 'improper convergent' and is a special form of divergent. Is that usually a different definition in english?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=\sin(e^x-1)/x$ otherwise. Then $f$ is continuously differentiable and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, but $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you. But is the proof under the additional assumption, that $f'$ converges, correct?

Comment: That seems to be fine, yes.